# Spring batch don't insert Job instances into database

Tags: java, spring-batch

I try to implement spring batch into existing environment.
my spring batch work correctly but it doesn't seem to insert instances into spring batch tables (Batch_job_execution,...)

I don't understand why it doesn't failed, and the statue of the batch is completed?

And how can I solve this problem and configure corretly my spring batch regarding already existing configuration?

I have a transactionManager configure as below : 
Common configuration of the project

```java
@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager myTxManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(myEmf().getObject());
}
```

My current spring batch configuration

```java
@Bean
@Override
public JobRepository getJobRepository() throws Exception {
    MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(getTransactionManager());
    factory.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_DEFAULT");
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
}

@Override
public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() throws Exception {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(getJobRepository());
    jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobLauncher;
}

@Override
public JpaTransactionManager getTransactionManager() throws Exception {
    return myTxManager;
}


@Override
public JobExplorer getJobExplorer() throws Exception {
    return this.jobExplorer;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean` creates a `JobRepository` that is backed by in memory `Map` implementations...not the database.  Use the `JobRepositoryFactoryBean` instead and you'll see the records in the database.